# Gradle - Type is defined multiple times, Android - Apache POI problems

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, apache-poi

I'm trying to use POI on android. I got this error. How can I fix it? Can I exclude something from dependencies?

```
Type org.apache.xmlbeans.metadata.system.sXMLCONFIG.TypeSystemHolder is defined multiple times: C:\Users\MSZ\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cc7d97ae12f5ddeb0f664fc91dcb9489\jetified-xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar:org/apache/xmlbeans/metadata/system/sXMLCONFIG/TypeSystemHolder.class, C:\Users\MSZ\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\cc7d97ae12f5ddeb0f664fc91dcb9489\jetified-xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar:org/apache/xmlbeans/metadata/system/sXMLCONFIG/TypeSystemHolder.class
```

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev110-1.23.0'
    implementation files('libs\\commons-collections4-4.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\commons-compress-1.20.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\poi-5.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\poi-ooxml-5.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\poi-ooxml-lite-5.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\xmlbeans-4.0.0.jar')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestimplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

I can also tell you, I can't get rid of xmlbeans dependency, because I get this exception

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.scanner-tO5vSzAMf2TMgMjcFMuIJg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.scanner-tO5vSzAMf2TMgMjcFMuIJg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at void com.test.scanner.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:55)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7224)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7213)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(a`ndroid.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:201)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:873)
 I/.barcodescanne: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorkbook>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;
    at void com.test.scanner.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:55)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7224)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7213)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:201)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.scanner-tO5vSzAMf2TMgMjcFMuIJg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.test.scanner-tO5vSzAMf2TMgMjcFMuIJg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
    at void com.test.scanner.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.java:55)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7224)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7213)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(android.app.ClientTransactionHandler, android.os.IBinder, android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions) (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at void android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction) (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:201)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I tried to clean and rebuild the project, it doesn't work. I tested POI in a desktop application. It works perfectly with these jar libraries.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. POI has problems on android. It works, I downloaded and added these two jars to build path:

1. poi-3.12-android-a.jar
2. poi-ooxml-schemas-3.12-20150511-a.jar

Download link:

https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx